# MVC Sliding form with jQuery tweaking (link to example)

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc

Im using the example from: 
http://tympanus.net/codrops/2010/06/07/fancy-sliding-form-with-jquery/

I want to be able to send a parameter to a function where i decide which tab was the last one. So for an example, if I'm on tab 3 and I click on tab 4, it will go from 3 to 4 and not 1 to 4 as it is now.

I have already made a function where i decide which tab i would like to start on so thats all done. But, I tried fiddling with the variables for hours now and I cant figure it out. Im new to javascript so im having a very hard time right now.. Would love some help!

Thanks a ton!

HTML:

```
<div id="content" style="margin-top:50px;">
    <div id="wrapper">
        <div id="steps">
            <fieldset class="step">
                <legend>www.ww.www</legend>
                @Html.Partial("~/Views/Folder/_Home.cshtml")
            </fieldset>
            <fieldset class="step">
                <legend>Tab1></legend>
                @Html.Partial("~/Views/Folder/_view1.cshtml")
            </fieldset>

            <fieldset class="step">
                <legend>Tab2</legend>
                @Html.Partial("~/Views/Folder/_view2.cshtml")
            </fieldset>

            <fieldset class="step">
                <legend>Tab3</legend>
                @Html.Partial("~/Views/Forgot/_view3.cshtml")
            </fieldset>
        </div>
        <div id="navigation" style="display:none;">
            <ul>
                <li class="selected">
                    <a href="#" id="option1">Tab1</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="#" id="option2">Tab2</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="#" id="option3">Tab3</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="#" id="option4">Tab4</a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Script for activating a specific tab:

```
<script>
    $(function () {
        var steps = jQuery("#option4");
        steps.click();
    })
</script>
```

This selects the last tab.

The code for the tabs: (not all, just the important part)

$(function () {
    /*
    number of fieldsets
    */
    var fieldsetCount = $('#formElem').children().length;

```
/*
current position of fieldset / navigation link
*/
var current = 1;

/*
sum and save the widths of each one of the fieldsets
set the final sum as the total width of the steps element
*/
var stepsWidth = 0;
var widths = new Array();
$('#steps .step').each(function (i) {
    var $step = $(this);
    widths[i] = stepsWidth;
    stepsWidth += $step.width();
});
$('#steps').width(stepsWidth);

/*
to avoid problems in IE, focus the first input of the form
*/
$('#formElem').children(':first').find(':input:first').focus();

/*
show the navigation bar
*/
$('#navigation').show();

/*
when clicking on a navigation link 
the form slides to the corresponding fieldset
*/
$('#navigation a').bind('click', function (e) {
    var $this = $(this);
    var prev = current;
    $this.closest('ul').find('li').removeClass('selected');
    $this.parent().addClass('selected');
    /*
    we store the position of the link
    in the current variable 
    */
    current = $this.parent().index() + 1;
    /*
    animate / slide to the next or to the corresponding
    fieldset. The order of the links in the navigation
    is the order of the fieldsets.
    Also, after sliding, we trigger the focus on the first 
    input element of the new fieldset
    If we clicked on the last link (confirmation), then we validate
    all the fieldsets, otherwise we validate the previous one
    before the form slided
    */
    $('#steps').stop().animate({
        marginLeft: '-' + widths[current - 1] + 'px'
    }, 500, function () {
        $('#formElem').children(':nth-child(' + parseInt(current) + ')').find(':input:first').focus();
    });
    e.preventDefault();
});
```

Its the same code as in the link, if its tough to read just check it out:) Thanks

Comment: Show some of your code :)

Comment: Its exactly the same as in the the link, but sure let me edit my first post one moment:)

Comment: But in the example link it functions as you require. It moves from the current tab to the next one. from 3 to 4

Comment: Ok firstly your option1 ID is appearing twice. Ids must be unique

Comment: Sorry its a typo dont mind that

Comment: Sorry for the mess, i updated the code. Its now exactly the same as my own

Comment: Am I missing something here? The plugin handles the current and previous step for you. Even if you explicitly give it a step it will always navigate from the current one - http://jsfiddle.net/gV5de/

Comment: "if I'm on tab 3 and I click on tab 4, it will go from 3 to 4 and not 1 to 4 as it is now." If i am on tab 3, and click tab 4, i am taken to tab 4. How do you mean it takes you 1 to 4?

Comment: Okey let me try and explain it.

If a user is on tab3 and i reload the page(user submits something on that tab), i can easily set it so it goes back to tab 3, BUT, it  navigates from first tab to the third(sliding), which i dont want. I want it to show tab3 without any sliding.

Comment: Again sorry for being unclear. Anyone close to a solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK - Here is a solution

If you look at the #steps element in the html you will notice that upon selecting a navigation item, it changes the margin-left property by -600pxs each time.

So all you need to do is update this depending on what menu item you want.

```
$('#steps').css( { "margin-left" : "-1800px" });
```

Then you just need to update the selected navigation item's class so it styled properly

```
$('#navigation ul li').removeClass('selected');
$('#navigation ul li').eq(3).addClass('selected');
```

Here is an updated JSFiddle with the code you need - http://jsfiddle.net/gV5de/1/

Hope this helps you